# How to replace Aurelia components?

Tags: components, aurelia

I'm newbie with Aurelia and frontend frameworks generally.
I have page with List

list.html

```
<template>
    <require from="services/list-item"></require>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row row-centered container-top-space">
            <div repeat.for="item of items">
                <list-item item.bind="item"></list-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

list.js

```
 import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
    import { HttpClient, json } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
    @inject(HttpClient)

    export class ListItem{
        constructor(httpClient) {
        this.items= [];

        httpClient.configure(...);
      }
    }
```

and ListItem

list-item.html

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-item">
            <div class="form-control-inline" style="width:33%">
                <span>${item.name}&ensp;&ensp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control-inline" style="width:54%">
            <span>${item.value}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right" style="width:100px">
            <button class="btn btn-list-item" type="submit" name="submit" click.delegate="edit($event.target.parentElement)">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

list-item.js

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class ListItem{
    @bindable item;

    edit(element){
        //I'd like to replace view component with update component here
    }
}
```

I'd like to change template of list-item on list-item-edit when edit function will be called, but completely don't know how to make it.

Comment: You may use show.bind or if.bind for both: list-item and listitem-edit

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, but I'm interesting in replacing of two components (DOM replacement). Thank you.

Comment: @Kici suggestion is the way to go. Just have your `list-item.html` template have the two components, and hide or show them with `show.bind` depending on a edit flag. It is possible to manipulate the DOM and replace the elements, but you are going to run into binding and scope issues. It is much easier to do it this way.

Comment: Thank you, I did it in that way, but I was wondering if it is possible in another way. Thank you.